# When updating some of the elements in an object array in Javascript, which one is a more efficient way considering the array size?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Consider this very simple js code below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if(rows[i].index !== i) {
        rows[i].index = i;
    }
}
```

Say, the length of the array is 8, and it will enter the if block 2 times. Is it better to do this way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].index = i;
}
```

I want to know which one is less costly with large arrays and small arrays; the if block, or the value assign in every cycle of the loop?

Comment: I would say the version without the if , but you should test it on jsperf

Comment: There's only one way to find out: measure it. But [you should not care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation), and go for the simpler one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it shouldn't really matter. I still [tried it on jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/arrayupdateso) for the sake of curiousity and it seems that the second version is faster.